# unable to puppet lookup a hiera interpolated hash

Tags: hiera

getting a string instead of array

this is my common.yaml

```
aa::params:

- '--params:"abc.com'

- 'abc2.com'


test::packages:

  package1:

    ensure:'present'

    install_options: "%{lookup('aa:params')}"
```

this is my manifest file

```
$packages = lookup("test::packages",undef,undef,'')

$params= lookup("aa::params",undef,undef,'')

$packages.each | String $packagename, Hash $attributes | {

notify { " ${packagename}, ${attributes[ensure]},${attributes['install_options]},${params} hello ":


  }

}
```

expected

```
"package1,present,[--params="abc.com, abc2.com"],[--params="abc.com, abc2.com"] hello"
```

actual

```
"package1,present,["--params=\"abc.com", "abc2.com\""],[--params="abc.com, abc2.com"] hello"
```

It looks like array is getting stringified can someone please explain why I am getting like this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interpolating the results of a lookup into a string always results in a string. If you want the actual array instead of a strigyfied version you should use `alias` instead. Your `common.yaml` would look something like this:

```
aa::params:
  - '--params:"abc.com'
  - 'abc2.com'

test::packages:
  package1:
    ensure:'present'
    install_options: "%{alias('aa:params')}"
```

Here is the [related documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/hiera/3.3/variables.html#the-alias-lookup-function).